# How to quantify the asymmetry of an image?

Tags: image-processing

Now I have two images:

[image: Asymmetric] [image: Symmetric]

We can see that Figure 1 shows obviously asymmetry while Figure 2 is totally symmetric. Now I would like to quantify the asymmetry of Figure 1. Is there any reliable and elegant way to do so? I can come up with the idea that calculate the difference and moment of the left and right side of the axis. while I want something better.

Comment: Is your mission to find _any_ symmetry and characterize it, or just find symmetry around the y-axis of the image, or what?  Are you limiting yourself to even or odd reflections, or are you concerned with rotational symmetries, tiling symmetries, etc.?  Please _expand your question_ so we know what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing you can do is just flip the image over the axis you want to quantify symmetry over, and compare the result with the original image. Simple pairwise image comparison could be correlation, mean square error (MSE), SSIM, or any other method. Your favorite image processing library should have at least a few different image pair comparison algorithms implemented.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is "even" about the center and real, the Fourier Transform will be real if the center was set to be the origin. The DFT starts at the origin, so the result will be a linear phase over the samples. We can remove the linear phase and then test if the result has any imaginary components. Comparing the real to imaginary would reveal the degree of asymmetry.

For a linear DFT (one row or column of the image) this can be done with the following:

```
import scipy.fftpack as fft
import numpy as np
n = len(row)
result = fft.fft(row) * np.exp(1j* np.arange(n) * 4*np.pi/n)
```

Following the pattern above can be extended to 2D FFT's. (The image would need to be perfectly centered on the origin of the image to be symmetric).

I made a simple 2D example of this to demonstrate, with the images on top and the 2D FFT below after compensation for linear phase offset, purple indicates 0 and yellow is maximum:

[image: demo]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as img
f = np.zeros((5,5))
f[2,2] = 15
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(f)
row = np.exp(1j*np.arange(5)*4*np.pi/5)
col = np.exp(1j*np.arange(5)*4*np.pi/5)
grid = col[:, None] * row[None, :]
H1 = np.fft.fft2(f)
vmin=0
vmax=15
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(5, 3))
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.title("Magnitude")
plt.imshow(np.abs(test), vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
plt.subplot(1,3,2)
plt.title("Real")
plt.imshow(np.real(test), vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
plt.subplot(1,3,3)
plt.title("Imag")
plt.imshow(np.imag(test), vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
```

For the offset image replace the line f[2,2]=15 with f[3,3]=15. The OP's images are not perfectly symmetric, so the result will not have zero imaginary components. Evaluating the average phase angle over all pixels in the FFT result should provide a reasonable metric proportional to asymmetry.